# Drupal commerce: product field based in calculation of other fields

Tags: entities, commerce

The commerce product has the field: **Price**

Then I added two more field: **Quantity** and **Price per Unit**

I need the field **Price per Unit** to take the calculated value from this:

```
Price per Unit = Price/Quantity
```

How I get this?

Answer (score 1):

Commerce out of the box has a quantity field and does by default a 'price-per-unit'. Watch this tutorial to give you an idea of how it works without any customizations.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KEJcieG4jI